# Ruby on Rails Model.find(): Two Queries instead of Subquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am receiving a set of models from my SQLite Database with Ruby on Rails 2.3.5. Currently I am using a subquery in order to select only the ones which I really want to have:

```rb
find(:all, 
  :conditions => "foo.id in (
                    SELECT bar.foo_id FROM bar
                    JOIN baz
                      ON baz.bar_id = bar.id
                    WHERE baz.bla in (1, 2, 3)
                  )"
)
```

I know this is stupid, because the subquery evaluates the same result for every row and I guess SQLite is not smart enough to notice that it could be optimized. So I would like to take it out of the query. I know that I could simply call it from Rails using a second `find()`, but given that the return value of the subquery may become relatively big, I would like to do everything in the database, so I don't need to juggle huge data between the Database and Rails.

So, how can I do the Model's `find()` and tell it, that it should look up the return value of my actual subquery and then use it's result for the comparison of my other rows? Can I pass this in one call of `find()` into SQLite?

Comment: Are you using the second table information for something in the results?

Comment: No. I only need it to select the right colums, the information **does not** need to be transported into the application.

Comment: Did you run an `EXPLAIN`? Why do you run SQLite if you care about speed?

Comment: Speed is not an issue at the moment, everything works fine. Nevertheless I am trying to set up the queries in a responsible way. As long as this does not require any additional effort and I am still able to write clean code there is nothing wrong with it, I think. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if you could do something like the following:

```
    subs = connection.select_rows("SELECT bar.foo_id FROM bar
                                   JOIN baz
                                   ON baz.bar_id = bar.id
                                   WHERE baz.bla in (1, 2, 3)")
    find(:all, :conditions => "foo.id in (#{subs.join(',')})")
```

Which is what I'd try to rewrite it to in Rails 3.

Comment: But that **does** send the data from SQLite back to the application which sends it in a second query to the database again, doesn't it? Can't I simply tell the Database *hey you, please use the selected values from this query in your next query*?

Comment: @YMMD - there is no way to accomlish your "hey database, please use the selected values in your next query" because outside of a procedural language each query is independent of all others. Sure you can wrap multiple queries in a transaction, but to actually grab results and store them in a temporary variable, inside the database, you need to drop down into your DB's procedural language system, such as Transact-SQL for SQL Server, pg/psql for Postgres, etc. So I think the 2 query approach above is really your best bet.

Comment: Cody: You are probably right. But still I have the feeling that this is not ideal. But since I see your point that this probably cannot be realized in a procedural language system, this still remains the best answer for me. @Tass: SQL Injections would not be a problem, since I am simply joining integer values which come from the primary key of my Database.

Comment: YMMD: You can achieve what you want in Postgres, but SQlite is a very simple database that doesn't support scripting or variables.

Comment: That is sad, but I guess there is nothing I can do against this, unless I change to another DB. I just implemented your answer and it worked perfectly. I think you deserve the bounty, because your answer concentrates on how to query for the things I need instead of defining minor relevant relationships. Thanks for your help, here come your 150 reputation points. :-) For anyone wondering: `connection` should be `ActiveRecord::Base.connection`.

Comment: Sorry for being absent for so long, the connection is not necessarily the ActiveRecord::Base one, since it is easy to have specific database connections per model in Rails 3. You can do ModelName.establish_connection(adapter: "mysql2", ...) for instance, to use a MySQL database for one model in a SQLite based application.

I intentionally left it out, so what you see is the instance or class methods used in the model.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should try to define your relations in models. That way you can easily use ActiveRecord's helpers

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "foo"

  has_many :bars
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "bar"

  belongs_to :foo
  has_many :bazs
end

class Baz < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "baz"

  belongs_to :bar
end
```

With these models in place, you can write the query similar to this:

```
Foo.find(:all, :include => {:bar => :baz}, :conditions => ["#{Baz.table_name}.id IN (?)", [1,2,3]])
```

Comment: Is Rails going to transform this into an optimized query as described in my question? If yes, then this would be the preferable solution,  but my test case will probably prove that it won't.

Comment: You can easily find out how the SQL looks by hooking .explain at the end of that find. :)

Comment: `.explain` was introduced in Rails 3.2, but sadly I am running Rails 2.3. Nevertheless you can see how it composes the query as soon as you put a syntax error in it. ;) @Holger: I don't really know if this is worth such a subtle definition of relationships, because what I am trying to query is really a special case. As you can see it also depends on another factor, which is not even stored in the database (currently expressed as the hardcoded `(1, 2, 3)` in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following models:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars
  has_many :bazs, :through => :bars

  attr_accessible :title
end


class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
  has_many :bazs

  attr_accessible :title
end


class Baz < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bar

  attr_accessible :title
end
```

You can:

```
Foo.all(
  :joins => { :bars => :bazs },
  :conditions => { :bars => { :bazs => { :id => [1000] } } }
)
```

Where `1000` is the id of the Baz you're interested in.

This will generate the following SQL:

```
SELECT "foos".* FROM "foos" INNER JOIN "bars" ON "bars"."foo_id" = "foos"."id" INNER JOIN "bazs" ON "bazs"."bar_id" = "bars"."id" WHERE "bazs"."id" IN (1000)
```

Which is the same if you did this:

```
Foo.all(
  :joins => { :bars => :bazs },
  :conditions => { :bazs => { :id => [1000] } }
)
```

Or even better, using the `through` association:

```
Foo.all(
  :joins => [:bazs],
  :conditions => { :bazs => { :id => [1000] } }
)
```

And the result will be all the Foo records that match that criteria, and the SQL will be the same.

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Your approach is very similar to Holger's version, so I can give an almost equal comment: I don't really know if this is worth such a subtle definition of relationships, because what I am trying to query is really a special case. As you can see it also depends on another factor, which is not even stored in the database (currently expressed as the hardcoded (1, 2, 3) in my example.

Comment: Well, in this cases I used `1000` as id, but you can represent something else. Now from your example `bla` is from the database and you're looking for different values for it (using `IN`). At no point there is mention `bla` is not from the database or computed anyway.